# Calling Function Pointer from argument in a class member that points to another class member

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have an error in `CLASS_A::Determine()` and I don't know what mistake I have made:

> expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type

```
class CLASS_A
{
private:
  double Calculate(int weldPt);
  double Determine(double lb, double ub, double(CLASS_A::*Result)(double, int));
}


double CLASS_A::Calculate(int weldPt)
{
  double LB, UB;
  ...  
  double x = Determine(LB, UB, &CLASS_A::Calculate); // Calling Determine() with Function Pointer argument
  ...
}


double CLASS_A::Determine(double lb, double ub, double(CLASS_A::*Result)(double, int))
{
  ...
  double X = Result(20.2, 10); // ERROR! expression preceding parentheses of apparent call 
                               // must have (pointer-to-) function type
  ...
}
```

I'm never good with Function Pointers, and using them in class makes me more confused.

Can anybody help me correct my code?

Comment: Can you provide some information on what you are trying to achieve? I find it hard to tell from your code. Passing a pointer-to-member-function to another member function of the same class smells a bit fishy to me. If you provide more context, someone here might point you in the right direction and maybe even a better solution. Until then, here is a *syntactically* correct version of your code, but I doubt that it does anything useful https://godbolt.org/z/7d6G73j7c

Comment: @joergbrech, Determine() is a function with complex numerical method that need an function to calculate a response value. There are 4 cases from 4 different call points and have 4 different functions to calculate response value. I didnt one to have 4 version of Determine() and I know function pointer is the way to go. But I have lack of experience using function pointer in a class. Anyway, PatricioLoncomilla have solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A member function pointer requires a class pointer to work. In this case, the "this" pointer is available:

```
double CLASS_A::Determine(double lb, double ub, double(CLASS_A::*Result)(double, int))
{
  double X = (this->*Result)(20.2, 10);
}
```

Comment: Nice @Patricio! I did try this->Result(20.2, 10); but I didn't know I have missing the bracket and *. Thank you very much!

Comment: Here is a good read: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#macro-for-ptr-to-memfn

Comment: @MuhamadIrwanAbdulHamid in modern C++, you should consider using [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) or a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of a pointer-to-member-function.

Comment: @RemyLebeau lambda is not preferred dur to the functions supplying result are long. However std::function seem a good alternative for readability. I will study and made amend. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @MuhamadIrwanAbdulHamid if `Determine()` takes a `std::function` or a templated `Callable`, a lambda can be used to call a class method, eg: `double CLASS_A::Calculate(int weldPt) { double LB, UB; ... double x = Determine(LB, UB, [this](double d, int i) { return Calculate(d, i); }); ... }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau not for lambda, cause there are 4 different functions to be called depending on case condition, or make code too dirty if force to use lambda. std::function is a good candidate to keep up with the modern style.

Comment: @IrwanHamid That is your choice, of course. Just be aware that `std::function` may have some overhead to it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would see, or just stick with the old function pointer. Now not the time to focus on those.